# Token recognition order

Tags: antlr4

My full grammar results in an incarnation of the dreaded "no viable alternative", but anyway, maybe a solution to the problem I'm seeing with this trimmed-down version can help me understand what's going on.

```
grammar NOVIA;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;  // whitespace rule -> toss it out

T_INITIALIZE : 'INITIALIZE' ;
T_REPLACING  : 'REPLACING' ;
T_ALPHABETIC : 'ALPHABETIC' ;
T_ALPHANUMERIC : 'ALPHANUMERIC' ;
T_BY         : 'BY' ;

IdWord : IdLetter IdSeparatorAndLetter* ;

IdLetter : [a-zA-Z0-9];
IdSeparatorAndLetter : ([\-]* [_]* [A-Za-z0-9]+);



FigurativeConstant :
      'ZEROES' | 'ZERO' | 'SPACES' | 'SPACE' 
;

statement :  initStatement ;

initStatement : T_INITIALIZE identifier+ T_REPLACING (T_ALPHABETIC | T_ALPHANUMERIC) T_BY (literal | identifier) ;

literal : FigurativeConstant ;

identifier : IdWord ;
```

and the following input

```
INITIALIZE ABC REPLACING ALPHANUMERIC BY SPACES
```

results in

```
(statement (initStatement INITIALIZE (identifier ABC) REPLACING ALPHANUMERIC BY (identifier SPACES)))
```

I would have expected to see SPACES being recognized as "literal", not "identifier".

Any and all pointer greatly appreciated,

TIA - Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every string that might match the `FigurativeConstant` rule will also match the `IdWord` rule.  Because the `IdWord` rule is listed first and the match length is the same with either rule, the Lexer issues an `IdWord` token, not a `FigurativeConstant` token.

List the `FigurativeConstant` rule first and you will get the result you were expecting.

As a matter of style, the order in which you are listing your rules obscures the significance of their order, particularly for the necessary POV of the Lexer and Parser.  Take a look at the grammars in the [antlr/grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) repository as examples -- typically, for a combined grammar, parser on top and a top-down ordering.  I would even hazard a guess that others might have answered sooner had your grammar been easier to read.

Comment: Thanks - do I feel stupid now ? Hazard a positive guess and you won't be wrong ..

In my frantic attempt to reproduce the NoViableAlt issue with a trimmed-down
grammar I just didn't pay enough attention to its style, sorry 'bout that.

I only swapped the "literal" and "identifier" rules, but not the lexer rules.

I'll try to attribute this to my fried brain cos of the 35°C we had yesterday
and hope I'll get away with it ;-)

So back to the drawing board as this didn't (and can't) solve my NoViableAlt with the full grammar.